# How to implement roles with JWT in Symfony 4

Tags: symfony, jwt, lexikjwtauthbundle

I did to implement JWT authentication with the extension lexik_jwt_authentication, but I want to implement different roles, for creation, editing and modification, but I don't know how to do it, could someone help me?

Comment: You'll need to create your own custom authentication. Did you try googling for a way to do this? [Here](https://symfonycasts.com/screencast/symfony-rest4/jwt-guard-authenticator) is the 3rd result I found.

Comment: Thanks i tried this option, but i couldn't manage diferent roles for especifics endpoints

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think your user roles are automatically included in your encoded JWT token (at least in the application I'm working currently). So you can manage your roles like you do it in any Symfony application.

Once the token decoded in your client, you can reuse them. To decode the token in your client, you will need to share the public key between your Symfony app and your client.